# CSS Image URLs not working when ran as Jar

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, javafx

So I have two problems.

My program structure:

[image]

In header.css I'm trying to set the image of an ImageView defined in the header.fxml with the class "pendantBG":

```
.pendantBG{
    -fx-image: url("../../../../../Game/images/ui/circlebg.png");
}
```

This is the only url that I can get to work when running the main class in intellij, but it gives two problems:

1) Intellij is throwing up a 'cannot resolve file' (Despite the image showing up as desired):
[image]

2) When building the jar and running it, the image doesn't show, and throws this error:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Edit: result of commands (from fabians comment)

[image]

Comment: Check, the resource paths in the jar: `jar -tf Game.jar | find "circlebg.png"` and `jar -tf Game.jar | find "header.css"`. I'm pretty sure `Game` is not part of the path...

Comment: Okay so I did that and edited in the result. I changed the url (removed the Game) part, and now the jar file correctly shows the image however now running the Main class from within intellij I'm getting a similiar error to before: (WARNING: Error loading image: file:/C:/Users/Home/Desktop/Game/out/production/images/ui/circlebg.png)

Comment: So 'solved' it by removing all the '../' so it was just  "/images/ui/circlebg.png". I don't fully understand how that works, (I also noted "images/ui/circlebg.png" doesn't work and I'm not sure why but not complaining too much)